# Alternative of case expression as it doesn't support '<' ,'>' and '=' in 'when'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, case

I want to change display new salaries of employees who has salary below 900 as new salary

```
SELECT 
    ename, 
    job, 
    sal , 
    CASE sal 
        WHEN sal<900 THEN sal+100         
        ELSE sal 
    END 'NewSalary'
FROM emp;
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>
> Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? That looks a lot like SQL Server error message -- and those are 2 totally different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `CASE` correctly.

Consider:

```
SELECT 
    ename, 
    job, 
    sal , 
    CASE WHEN sal<900 THEN sal+100 ELSE sal END NewSalary 
FROM emp;
```

Note: there is a syntax that allows the use of `CASE <expr> WHEN <value> THEN ...`, but that only works to check if the expression is *equal* to the value, and does not support other comparisons than equality.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't need a CASE statement since MySql evaluates boolean expressions like `sal < 900` as `1` for `TRUE` and `0` for `FALSE`:

```
SELECT 
    ename, 
    job, 
    sal,
    sal + (sal < 900) * 100 NewSalary
FROM emp;
```

So if `sal < 900` then the result will be `sal + 100` because `sal < 900` will evaluate to `1`, but when `sal >= 900` the result will be `sal` because `sal < 900` will evaluate to `0`.

Comment: Nice solution as well, although maybe less easy to understand at first sight.